# How to build Animator slide up/down in XML for android?

Tags: android, animation

I've been trying to find out how to build an animator (xml) that will cause a slide up and slide down effect. How would that work? Thanks

Comment: If you are animating views, and are ok with a programmatic response, look into [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidQuery)'s way: `$.with(view).slideUp()` and `$.with(view).slideDown()`.

Comment: How would it be used in a fragment transaction though? if I want to add a fragment and cause a slide up animation?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make a folder anim in the res folder of the project.
Now add slide_up.xml for slide_up animation.
Then add slide_down.xml for slide down animation.

Code for slide_down.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Code for slide_up.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toYDelta="1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Then load the animation in onCreate method consequently:

```
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
```

To start it attach it to object you want to be animated:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
img.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

Hope I've helped you. :-)

Comment: As there is only one `translate` involved in each xml file, you don't need the `set` element wrapped round it. Though if you are using appcompat_v7 you don't need the xml files at all, just use `R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom` and `R.anim.abc_slide_out_bottom`