# Swipe imageview to pull up layout with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In my app, I have a `TableLayout` with 6 items in it and on that layout I have attached `ImageView` with controller like button.

This is the scheme:

[image]

So basically I have 3 components here:

1. Checker img that will bring bot navigation top and down
2. Bottom navigation with icons.

I manage to implement it partially  with this

```
controller.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View b=findViewById(R.id.botmenuLayout);
        if (b.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

so when user press on Controller image view will gone and when he press it again view will return.

It's working but I get no animation. I tried many tutorials found on StackOverflow but it didn't help me

Comment: You can try this for animation http://stackoverflow.com/a/18279761/3416642

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [BottomSheet](http://www.materialdoc.com/bottom-sheets/) pattern. Try to follow the the tutorial, for example [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031)